# How to Use WCF objects to create a Report?

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, rdlc

In Visual Studio 2010, how do you create a report using a List returned from a WCF call?

Comment: You mean to use the WCF call instead of a database query?

Comment: What I was trying to do was have a WCF call be the datasource for a RDLC.  Just wrapped the WCF call in a method that returned the list of objects and the designer picked it up and let me use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this article here:

[Reporting Services: Using XML and Web Service Data Sources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964129%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

It explains in great detail how to attach data from a web service as a data source into a Reporting Services report.